# Solvent + Photopolymer Waste Disposal

Tags: everyday-chemistry, polymers, safety, cleaning

I have a 3L jug of SLA printer-related waste that's been sitting under my desk for a while now and I'd really like to finally figure out how to get rid of it. It contains:

- Ethanol (primarily) and isopropanol, saturated (in the literal sense) with uncured resin (photo-polymers, photo-initiators, binders). Note there is likely very little water left (started with 90% ethanol and 99% iso, sieve-dried multiple times).
- About 10% by volume undissolved waste, a slimy gray slurry of: uncured resin, a significant concentration of glass fibers, and some uninteresting filter waste (charcoal, sodium bentonite, probably some sieve dust, etc.)

Also it smells awful when unsealed, numerous recyclings through filters have left it disproportionately saturated with god knows what. It smells like ... pine and cancer.

How do I get rid of this? Is there some way I can process it myself to make it environmentally friendly? The uncured photopolymers are the worst offender, I believe. Plus the whole thing is very flammable.

Location: NYC (Kings County), NY USA

Also: I don't mind going through the effort of processing it myself if it keeps it out of the ocean or some landfill somewhere. Plus, I'll be continuing to generate this waste in the future (low volumes; probably about 1L per month at the highest rate) so I don't mind investing in a processing setup.

Comment: Normally you confer wastes to an appropriate service/company

Comment: In which country are you living ? In my country, such wastes are sent to waste collection centres which are organized in every little town.

Comment: @Alchimista Do they generally accept such small amounts? When I think of disposal services for some reason I always think industrial scale.

Comment: @Maurice I've added location info. NYC, NY USA.

Comment: @Alchimista Also; do disposal companies usually dispose of things in some responsible way, or do they end up being a USCSB case study some day (lol)? I don't mind going through the effort of processing it myself if it keeps it out of the ocean or some landfill somewhere. Plus, I'll be continuing to generate this waste in the future (low volumes; probably about 1L per month at the highest rate) so I don't mind investing in a processing setup.

Comment: @Jason C. In my country, Switzerland, waste materials are burnt in big waste collection  centers, and the heat produced is used for heating the houses and buildings in the vicinity. I am pretty sure it should be more or less the same in New York, NY. They may have thrown away household wastes down to the ocean. But it is simply not possible to still do it today.

Comment: @JasonC even university department find more convenient to pay for regulated disposal. The volume / mass are considerably more than your projected one. Of course, we have to trust our institutions...For the scale they do accept I have honestly no idea. There might even be a city run service to which you physically go when amount are so small. In all cases you have to look for rules in your county so you will find out how to proceed.